# Desk Check Binary Search

Tags: search, binary, desk-check

I am here about a query that I am facing.

I was wondering on how I would go about desk checking the following code.

Data set

```
0 1  2 3  4   5  6  7   8   9  10  11   12  13  14 15

4 7 19 25 36 37 50 100 101 205 220 271 306 321 456 500 /* Numbers are a bit messed up */
```

Algorithm
binarySearch

```
SET found TO FALSE
SET bottom TO zero
SET top TO sizeOfList-1
WHILE ( NOT found AND bottom <= top )
    SET middle TO (bottom+top) DIV 2
    IF searchValue < list element middle THEN
        SET top TO middle-1
    ELSE
        IF searchValue > list element middle THEN
            SET bottom TO middle+1
        ELSE
            SET position TO middle
            SET found TO TRUE
        ENDIF
    ENDIF
ENDWHILE

IF NOT found THEN
    RETURN –1
ELSE
    RETURN position
ENDIF
```

Comment: There are so many C implementations of this operation out there..

Comment: What exactly is the question/problem here?

Comment: Hi, oli. 

Question: I was wondering on how I would go about "Desk Checking" an Algorithm. Basically a walkthrough for sorting and searching but I really don't have a good grasp of desk checking. 

I looked over an example about grading which seemed straight forward but this looks a bit complicated and I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to first draw up a table, with one column for each variable (`found`, `bottom`, `top`, etc.).  Then, "be" the computer, step through your program code one line at a time (probably best to write down each line number that you visit to keep track), taking the conditional branches based on the values in your table.  Every time you modify a variable, add a new row to your table with the updated values.  Eventually, you should reach a `return` statement, and then you're done.

Comment: So basically (Found = False, Bottom = 0, Top = Sizeoflist 15-1?, 

What I don't understand is how is top worked out, if Found (false) + bottom (0). I don't understand how they add together or produce top..

Comment: @Gary: You mean the first `WHILE`?  Just read it as English: "while not found and `bottom` is less than or equal to `top` [then do everything up to the matching `ENDWHILE`]".  You would make life easier on yourself if you indented your code to follow the nesting of the loops and so on.

Comment: @Oli, I think i've managed it. Would you mind checking it over for me?

I used 3 as the value.

Found - False //
Bottom - Zero //
Top - 14 //
Middle - 7 //
Top - 6 //
Position - Middle //
Found - True //

Comment: @Gary: You've missed the line `SET middle TO (bottom+top) DIV 2`.  Note also that `SET position TO middle` means set the value of `position` to be the same as the value of `middle`, i.e. *copy* its value.  So if `middle` is e.g. `5`, then `position` should become `5` as well.

Comment: In the paste bin, I halfed bottom + top which was 14 to 7 in middle. And thanks, misread the set position to middle part

Comment: @Gary: Oh, so you did; I got confused by the fact that you had set the value of `position` on line 2.  Also, I would say that `sizeoflist` is 16, not 15...

Comment: @Gary: Also, it looks like you are doing `SET top TO middle-1` on line 6, and then `SET position TO middle` immediately afterward, which is not possible.

Comment: How so, I've layed it out so that it goes in the correct order of what happens. Or is there a better way to do that?

Comment: @Gary: Take a look at the program code in your question now that I've indented it.  That should make it more obvious that during the same iteration of the loop, you cannot do both `SET top TO middle-1` and `SET position TO middle`.

Comment: Ahhhh so your suggesting I put in a extra line between them due to this "IF searchValue < list element middle THEN"?

Comment: @Gary: No, I'm saying that after `SET top TO middle-1`, the next thing the program does is go back to the start of the while loop for the next iteration, because everything else is contained inside the `ELSE`.  So the next modification should be due to a second visit to the `SET middle TO (bottom+top) DIV 2` line.

Comment: Sorry but i am really confused now : / Any further information you could provide?

Comment: @Gary: An `IF` - `ELSE` - `ENDIF` construct either executes the code between the `IF` and the `ELSE`, or between the `ELSE` and the `ENDIF`.  Never both.

Comment: Right, Sorry for taking up most of your time. Much appreciated.

during the "IF searchValue < List element middle THEN" this is where I add the value 3. 

This then causes it to SET top to Middle -1. Correct?

Is that the right order now? Or am I still being stupid :(

Comment: @Gary: Yes, that's exactly it.  The "condition"/"test" on the `IF` line decides whether to continue inside the `IF`-`ELSE` section, or inside the `ELSE`-`ENDIF` section.

Comment: So is that everything that is needed to be provided? If so, you've been a fantastic help!